# intra-day trading information (OHLC and volume) for YRIV for specific dates in 2018

Tags: equities

I am doing reseaerch at the University of Minnesota (where I teach) for a class in investment banking, using YRIV as a case study.  How can I find intra-day trading information (OHLC and volume) for this stock, for specific dates in 2018?  Thank you.

Comment: In addition, I'd expect that the university to have access to paid resources (generally not named in the linked question) for academic use, is that not the case?